# WebDeployment is not

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, continuous-integration, web-deployment, continuous-deployment

I am trying to deploy an web application that was created on VB with the .NET Framework 2.0 using the TFS 2017 continuous deploy. It doesn’t have a solution file inside like vbproj or csproj, so I needed to avoid all the suggestions to include extra information on the vbproj.In order to run the MSBuild even locally I need to change in my .sln this **tag**, so all my compiled code is also there

Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "....\PrecompiledWeb\ARB\Debug\"

Unfortunately, I can’t deploy the application using the TFS. So far I tried to deploy it through my Visual Studio project, and is working fine with every option:  I tried MSDeploy, Web Deploy Package, and FileSystem, and is working fine from the Visual Studio Publish Option

[image]

With that, even my transformation take place.
Now lets say I go to my TFS and I put this parameters on the MSBuild

[image]

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsASingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="\\MyServer\Content"
```

My files are compiled but never stored in my Content folder. No one of them!!! I can’t figure out what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, you are using a Web Site project, not a Web Application project. The output structure of a Web Site project in TFS is different from build in VS (you can see a PrecompiledWeb folder in your build source directory on build agent server). Instead of using MSBuild argument, you can consider add tasks below to copy the files you want to publish:

[image]

We strongly suggest you switch from Web Site projects to Web Application projects to avoid these issues.

Comment: Hi @Cece, actually that is my workaround now, I am copying the files. But when you add the Copy Files task it copies all the files you have to the server, including all the web.config profiles(everything). With the Visual Studio I can create even a zip package to deploy, why I can't do that with the tfs, I am missing something here, because I am putting the same parameters to the MSBuild that I am seeing on the xml profile that I want to publish

Comment: When using Copy Files task, you can specify match pattern filters (one on each line) that you want to apply to the list of files to be copied, so that you don't need to copy all files. It's suggested to migrate from web site project to web application project for better experience.